# Xamarin: Text of Labels in StackLayout not fully shown

Tags: c#, xamarin, label, stacklayout

I'm coding a HangMan game on mobile and I have a StackLayout with Labels in it. Each label represents one letter of the chosen word, for example, t e s t w o r d.
So now my problem is the following: (It's all german, the letters I mean are the underlined ones and sry that the picture is that huge)
[image]

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="SPLetters" Spacing="9">
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter1" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter2" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter3" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter4" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter5" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter6" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter7" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter8" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter9" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter10" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter11" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter12" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter13" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter14" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter15" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter16" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblLetter17" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

I hope you can see that big letters like "A" or "H" are not fully shown. It seems like they're cut off by something and I don't know why.

I already tried to define a CharacterSpacing in each label but it didn't solve the problem. Padding also didn't work.

I hope you guys see the problem and can help me out!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the relevant xaml/code to your question please?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry here you go @haldo

Comment: you can reduce the Spacing="9" in the stack.

Comment: specify a `WidthRequest` value for the Labels, reduce the value of `Spacing`

Comment: This issue seems that is caused by the width of the parent is not enough.So you can try to add the `<ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>` to the grid.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT where exactly should I do that? In my Grid.ColumnDefinitions?

Comment: Yes, had you tried the method Jason and Amjad S provided? The two method should work.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT so Amjad S's method doesn't really work. it only makes the whole stack layout wider/tighter. But the labels are still cut off. The WidthRequest changes nothing, even with HorizontalOption Center

Comment: The <ColumnDefinition Width=auto/> also doesn't work. I have many grids with specified grid.columns etc so I need the width for every single column to be "*"

Comment: You can try to reduce the size of the text and add a label to test the issue will appear even when you set the value in the xaml or not. Such as`<Label x:Name="lblLetter17" TextDecorations="Underline" Text="A"/>`

Comment: So, the label is covered even when I set the Text in the xaml. I'm just wondering why I can't set a WidthRequest for the label. I set it to 100 and nothing happened, even if I set the HorizontalOptions to Center. Because seems like the label is just to small to show the whole letter. A wider label should work then

Comment: The parent view of the label is the StackLayout, so you can try to delete `HorizontalOptions="Center"` in the stacklayout or set a big widthrequest for it.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I tried, didn't work. I'll quit Xamarin... Seems to be buggy and it's not fun to work with :(

Comment: This issue is strange and I can't repeat it. Have you tried reduce the size of the Text?

Comment: Yeah, it's because there are too many letters. But it's dumb. If Xamarin would show the whole letters, it would work.

Comment: You can try to add a space for the text value, such as `Text = "H "`.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT nvm. it's not because of the text length. with a word length of 17, I can display the word `testtesttesttestt` without problems. But something with H's I can't. The H is literally to wide to display completely xD What a weird bug

Comment: I known that, I guess that the cause is the style of the text which seems bold. So give a space at the end to make the text show completely.

Comment: Also doesn't work, but hey, I already gave up on Xamarin